# Install python package for root user use

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, systemd

I've read all over, and I still can't get my python script to run in systemd.
Here is the shell script I use:

```
#! /bin/sh
cd /home/albert/speedcomplainer
/usr/bin/python speedcomplainer.py
```

I can execute the script (`/usr/bin/speedcomplainer`), it runs just fine from the command line.  The python script loops forever, checking my internet speeds.  As I said, it runs fine, from the command line directly (python ...) or from the shell script I created in usr/bin.

But when I put it into this unit file:

```
# speedcomplianer - checks and tweets comcast speeds.
#
#

[Unit]
Description=Ethernet Speed Complainer
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/albert/speedcomplainer
ExecStart=/usr/bin/speedcomplainer
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It fails to startup (`sudo systemctl start speedcomplainer.service`) with this error:

```
 speedcomplainer.service - Ethernet Speed Complainer
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/speedcomplainer.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2016-02-24 20:21:02 CST; 7s ago
  Process: 25325 ExecStart=/usr/bin/speedcomplainer (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 25325 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I look at the log with `journalctl -u speedcomplainer` and :

```
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven systemd[1]: Started Ethernet Speed Complainer.
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven speedcomplainer[25325]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven speedcomplainer[25325]: File "speedcomplainer.py", line 9, in <module>
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven speedcomplainer[25325]: import twitter
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven speedcomplainer[25325]: ImportError: No module named twitter
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven systemd[1]: speedcomplainer.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven systemd[1]: speedcomplainer.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven systemd[1]: speedcomplainer.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven systemd[1]: speedcomplainer.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 24 20:21:02 haven systemd[1]: Stopped Ethernet Speed Complainer
```

AHAHA!! An import error in the python script.

But wait - it works from everywhere else.  Why am I getting an Import error only when it runs from systemd? (Answer - the module is installed locally. Next question:)

OK.  After following the path that @jcomeau_ictx lead me down, it seems that pip installed to my local user directory.  How do I install modules for root use?

Comment: Where is the `twitter` module installed?

Comment: I installed the twitter module using pip from the command line.  (no virtual env, etc)

Comment: BTW, I can make the script available. but since it runs well by itself, I don't think it's pertinent.

Comment: did you install with `pip install --user twitter`? and does systemd run as root? if so, there's your problem.

Comment: I did not install with - - user.  Systemd does run as root, as I understand

Answer (score 1):

OK.  Thanks to [jcomeau_ictx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493161/jcomeau-ictx), I figured out the problem.  pip installs locally, by default.  This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95037/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-packages) discussed in detail how to install systemwide (TL;DR apt-get.).  This installed for the root user.  I didn't want to mess with a virtual env, and it's only one module with few dependencies.